# Where clause on MYSQL only returns data for one date

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i tried to query my DB (mysql workbench) using:

```
select * 
from dailyreport.salesreport 
where play_type = 'Subscription' 
and date = '2018-03-29';
```

this query returns data only for when **date = 2018-03-28** but doesnt return data for other dates **(from 2018-02-17 till 2018-04-10**).
NOTE: All date was imported from excelCSV files for each date.
DB SAMPLE BELOW.

```
date        drawdate    msisdn        tickets play_type
2018-02-16  2018-02-16  3xxxxxxxxxxxx   1    On-Demand
2018-02-16  2018-02-16  3xxxxxxxxxxxx   1    On-Demand
2018-02-16  2018-02-16  3xxxxxxxxxxxx   1    Subscription
2018-02-16  2018-02-16  3xxxxxxxxxxxx   1    Subscription
2018-02-19  2018-02-19  3xxxxxxxxxxxx   1    On-Demand
2018-02-20  2018-02-20  3xxxxxxxxxxxx   1    On-Demand
2018-02-20  2018-02-20  3xxxxxxxxxxxx   1    Subscription
2018-02-20  2018-02-20  3xxxxxxxxxxxx   2    On-Demand
```

Comment: Yes, that it's what is suposed to do, gets only the rows you said in your WHERE clause. If you want all days, remove the **and date = '2018-03-29'**

Comment: It is because your query says date = '2018-03-29', so no other dates will show; Your sample data is also not the same with your query. Please give us your expected result as well

Comment: Thanks for the info/status report. Was there a *question*? Or was this meant to be an answer to some other question?

Comment: i mean i get data for only 2018-03-28 when i filter by "play_type"  i dont ever get data for other dates when i filter by "play_type"

Answer (score 0):

You might mean give me all subscriptions irrespective of date and all play_types for '2018-03-29' in which case your where clause should be

```
where play_type = 'Subscription' 
OR date = '2018-03-29';
```